# Is it possible to symbolicate hex addresses ON an iOS device?

Tags: objective-c, device, symbolicate

I'm trying to implement a crash reporter for an app I'm working on.  The basic idea is that I want to send a notification to my server every time my app crashes.  I've gotten it to the point where I have all the stack frames and addresses, but ideally, I want to symbolicate the addresses before sending the error report.  Is it possible to access the .dSYM/.app files programmatically within my application?  I realize that I can symbolicate the hex addresses in the stack frames from the console, but I'd like to accomplish this on the device itself before sending the error report.  Anyone know if this is a possibility?  And if it is, any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Comment: The guy who posted the following question seems to know how to symbolicate the addresses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851211/what-do-the-memory-addresses-in-iphone-crash-logs-signify . Try to get in touch with him/her.